# Nested struct in a struct

Tags: apache-spark, data-structures

Given some rows coming from a SQL data source with an schema like...

```
| A | B | C | D | E | F |
```

... I'd like to transform it into:

```
{
    A: {
       invented: { B, C }
       D, 
       E
       F
    }
}
```

AFAIK, `dataFrame.withColumn` won't let me implement such transformation (it doesn't support nesting a struct into a first-level struct)

Is my goal ever possible?

Comment: I understand that everything will be nested inside A, but where does value of column A go? The same question for B and C. Can you add actual schema and maybe one sample data.

Comment: Yes, maybe I've not presented the issue as clear as needed., but as of your answer, you've correctly got the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to @partlov and his answer. Actually, when I first posted my question, I forgot to mention that some nested struct had to own an unexistent column.

That said, the issue was very easy to resolve.

My first attemp was:

```cs
 dataFrame.WithColumn("invented",
                Struct
                (
                    Struct("invented2", "A"),
                ))
```

But this was throwing an exceptions: Spark complained "could not resolve 'invented'" because `invented` isn't in the schema.

Then I realized that I could try to don't provide `"invented"` at all. And it worked, but Spark created `col1`. Finally, I tried to alias `col1`, and it has solved the issue!

```cs
 dataFrame.WithColumn("invented",
                Struct
                (
                    Struct("invented2", "A").As("X"),
                ));
```

Note: above sample is C# code, and I'm using [.NET for Spark](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/data/spark). Anyway, it should work the same way in Scala, Python, Java, R...

Answer (score 1):

I think that following code should work (if I understood correctly your question):

```
df
  .withColumn("nested_struct", struct(
      col("A"),
      struct(
        col("B"),
        struct(
          col("C"),
          struct(col("E"), col("F"))
        ),
        col("D")
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Let me try again this, because I believe that this is what has produced an exception.

Comment: Sure. If so, please post an error you got.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Please check my updated question. Actually I forgot to add the problem of adding an invented struct column, and nesting the other ones. This is my actual issue.

Comment: Actually it would be something like a `withColumn` nested into a root `withColumn`...

Comment: It's curious: `dataFrame.WithColumn("settings",
                Struct
                (
                    Struct(Column("description")),
                    Column("logoUrl"),
                    Column("url")
                ))`

This works and it created a `col1` which owns a `description` property. Nice. But if I give `Column("x")` to the nested `Struct`, I get an exception complaining that `x` can't be resolved, since it doesn't exist in the schema.